# How to organize test classes with interdependencies?

Tags: phpunit, integration-testing

I have multiple test classes and test cases in these classes depends on test case from other classes. I am writing `Integration Test` for `OpenSearch`.

I have a `CreatePostTest` class which tests the creating a document in `OpenSearch`. Then I have `UpdatePostTest` class which tests the updating the existing document in `OpenSearch`. So for updating the document I first run `CreatePostTest` and grab the ID of new document and use it in `UpdatePostTest`

```
class CreatePostTest
{
    public function testCreateDocument(): string
    {
        $postMock = $this->getBaseMockData();
        $response = $this->getCreatePostRequest($postMock);
        self::assertResponseSuccessful($response);
        $post = $response['data']['createPost']['post'];

        return $post['_id'];
    }

    //Other test cases
}

class UpdatePostTest
{
    public function testUpdateDocument(string $postId)
    {
        $postMock = $this->getBaseMockData();
        $postMock['postId'] = $postId;
        $response = $this->getUpdatePostRequest($postMock);
        self::assertResponseSuccessful($response);
    }

    //Other test cases
}
```

I have tried using `@depends` annotation but that give me error `This test depends on "App\Tests\Integration\Api\Post\UpdatePostTest::CreatePostTest" which does not exist.`

I have multiple such classes with interdependencies and I don't want to put all test cases in the same Test class.

What is the best way to organize such test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set Dependencies for classes. However, using a testsuite, you can define the order.

Here is an example of an API test. The SecurityControllerTest generates a JWT token that is needed in the UserControllerTest.

```xml
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="First Tests">
        <file>tests/Controller/SecurityControllerTest.php</file>
        <file>tests/Controller/UserControllerTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>

    <testsuite name="Following Tests">
        <directory>tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

**Update my answer because of a question in the comment:**

I use Symfony for the API. The API is sessionless. The tests are ApiTestCases. I alienate Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MockFileSessionStorage to store the JWT token during the tests. This meant I did not have to implement a filebased cache/storage myself. With MockFileSessionStorage I have a key-value storage and I do not have to do anything more.

Using a cache component (FilesystemAdapter or ArrayAdapter) was too much work for me at the time. In my opinion, the ArrayAdapter would also have to be integrated into a Singelton for it to work.

```php
namespace App\Tests\Mock;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class MockFileSessionStorage
{
    public static function getSession(): Session
    {
        $session = new Session(
            new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\MockFileSessionStorage(
                realpath(__DIR__ . '/../var')
            )
        );
        $session->setId('key');
        return $session;
    }
}
```

In the test method in which the JWT token is in the response body after successful authentication.

```php
// SecurityControllerTest
public function testAuthSuccessAndIsJwtTokenInResponseBody()
{
    $session = MockFileSessionStorage::getSession();
    $session->clear();

    // stuff

    $responseData = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    $session->set('jwt_token', $responseData['token']);
    $session->save();
}
```

This method is an abstract class that other test controllers also need.

```php
// AbstractController
public function getJwtAuthHeader(array $options): array
{
    if (false === isset($options['headers'])) {
        $options['headers'] = [];
    }
    $session = MockFileSessionStorage::getSession();
    $options['headers']['Authorization'] = sprintf('Bearer %s', $session->get('jwt_token'));
    return $options;
}
```

And the call in UserControllerTest.

```php
// UserControllerTest
public function testUpdateAction(): void
{
    $options = [];
    $options = $this->getJwtAuthHeader($options);
    $response = static::createClient()->request('PUT', '/api/users', $options);
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: How `JWT token` is passed from `SecurityControllerTest` to `UserControllerTest`? can you include the test case implementation?

Comment: @fahadshaikh I have extended my answer.